# Jquery param alternative for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to convert following type dictionary:

```
{'key1': ['value1'], 'key2': ['value1', 'value2']}
```

to `key1=value1&key2=....`

i.e. post data form. I am doing this inside chrome extention, the above dictionary of formdata is returned by:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
      if(details.method=="POST")         // ajax call
      {
        message.postdata = details.requestBody.formData;
      }
      return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
 }, {urls: ["<all_urls>"],types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]}, ["blocking", "requestBody"]);
```

I remeber achieving the same using **JQuery $.params()** function. How can the same be done in javascript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function queryParams(source) {
  var array = [];

  for(var key in source) {
     array.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(source[key]));
  }

  return array.join("&");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for nested objects.  The answer below by @ryeballar figured it out

Answer (score 12):

This is a [mini jquery param API](http://jsfiddle.net/bom09qjg/) [fiddle].

You can use it through `jqMini.param(obj);`

as shown in the fiddle above, it provides the same
output with jquery's original $.param function.

Note: jqMini.param does not handle the traditional jquery
objects as parameters.

```js
(function(w) {
    var app = {},
        class2type = {},
        toString = class2type.toString,
        r20 = /%20/g,
        rbracket = /\[\]$/;
    
    w.jqMini = app;
    
    app.type = function(obj) {
        if ( obj == null ) {
            return obj + "";
        }
        // Support: Android < 4.0, iOS < 6 (functionish RegExp)
        return typeof obj === "object" || typeof obj === "function" ?
            class2type[ toString.call(obj) ] || "object" :
        typeof obj;
    };
    
    app.isFunction = function(obj) {
        return app.type(obj) === "function";
    };
    
    app.buildParams = function(prefix, obj, add) {
        var name, key, value;
        
        if(Array.isArray(obj)) {
            for(var key in obj) {
                value = obj[key]
                if(rbracket.test(prefix))
                    add(prefix, value);
                else
                    app.buildParams(prefix + "[" + (typeof value === "object"? key: "") + "]", value, add );
            }
        } else if(app.type(obj) === 'object') {
            for(name in obj)
                app.buildParams(prefix + "[" + name + "]", obj[name], add);
        } else
            add(prefix, obj);
    };
    
    app.param = function(obj) {
        var prefix, key, value
        serialized = [],
            add = function(key, value) {
                value = app.isFunction(value)? value() : (value == null ? "" : value );
                serialized[serialized.length] = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
            };
        
        if(Array.isArray(obj)) {
            for(key in obj) {
                value = obj[key];
                add(key, value);
            }
        } else {
            for(prefix in obj)
                app.buildParams(prefix, obj[prefix], add);
        }
        
        return serialized.join('&').replace(r20, '+');
    };
    
})(window);

var obj = {'key1': ['value1'], 'key2': ['value1', 'value2']};
console.log(jqMini.param(obj));
```

Comment: Dude you should create a Gist with this code. Honestly it's being quite unused in this answer. I needed an alternative to $.param() for data obtained from a form by Angular JS and using jquery just for that was killing me. Thanks a lot!! +1

Comment: i is undefined in `app.buildParams(prefix + "[" + (typeof v === "object"? i: "") + "]", value, add );`

Comment: Can anyone explain what v and i are in this line
` app.buildParams(prefix + "[" + (typeof v === "object"? i: "") + "]", value, add );`

Comment: I am really curious where did you get v and i here `    app.buildParams(prefix + "[" + (typeof v === "object"? i: "") + "]", value, add );`

Comment: The `v` and `i` are the `value` and `key` variables. I've created this fiddle 5 years ago, and I guess I messed up when I was testing it.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you using AngularJS, you might want to check out [$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with - it has the same array handling as jQuery param.

```
var queryParam = function( ary ) {
    return Object.keys( ary ).map( function( key ) {
        if ( Array.isArray( ary[key] ) ) {
            var arrayParts = [];
            for ( var i = 0; i< ary[key].length; i++ ) {
                arrayParts.push( encodeURIComponent( key + '[]' ) + '=' + encodeURIComponent( ary[key][i] ) );
            }
            return arrayParts.join( '&' );
        }
        return encodeURIComponent( key ) + '=' + encodeURIComponent( ary[key] );
    }).join('&');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const data = {'key1': ['value1'], 'key2': ['value1', 'value2']};

const p = new URLSearchParams();
Object.keys(data).map((k) => data[k].map((v) => p.append(k+"[]",v)));

console.log(p.toString());
```

Output: key1%5B%5D=value1&key2%5B%5D=value1&key2%5B%5D=value2