# Send data to a php script with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS and following some tutorials I was able to create a simple page and a simple form.

The problem is that every time I submit the form seems that the script is sending empty data.

This is my html:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Contatti</h1>

        <p ng-show="message">{{ message }}</p>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <form ng-submit="processForm()">
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorName }">
                <label>Nome</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="chris" ng-model="formData.name">
                 <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorName">{{ errorName }}</span> 
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large">
                Salva
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<pre>
    {{ formData }}
</pre>
```

This is the js:

```
//Creo il modulo e includo ngRoute come dipendenza
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);


//Configuro le routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })

        .when('/chi-siamo', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/chi-siamo.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })

        .when('/contatti', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/contatti.html',
            controller: 'contactController'
        });

});

//Creo il controller che gestisce la home
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Sono in home";
});

//Controller che gestisce la pagina chi-siamo
scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Sono in Chi siamo";
});


//Controller che gestisce la pagina contatti
scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.processForm = function(){


        console.log($scope.formData);

        $http.post('process.php', $scope.formData)
             .success(
                function(data){

                    console.log(data);

                    if( data.success )
                    {
                        $scope.message = data.message;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
                    }

                }
             );
    }
});
```

and this is a very simple php script:

```
<?php
// process.php

$errors = array();  // array to hold validation errors
$data = array();        // array to pass back data


// validate the variables ========
if (trim($_POST['name']) == '')
  $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

// return a response ==============

// response if there are errors
if ( count($errors) > 0 ) {

  // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
  $data['success'] = false;
  $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {

  // if there are no errors, return a message
  $data['success'] = true;
  $data['message'] = 'Success!';
}

// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
```

Even if I write some data in my input in the console I get:

```
Object {success: false, errors: Object}
errors: Object
name: "Name is required."
__proto__: Object
success: false
__proto__: Object
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the reason below; Hope this helps.

Comment: try to print all POST <?php print_r($_POST); ?> to see what is wrong

Comment: Please show the code for `processForm()`

Comment: @BrentWashburne, just scroll the code and you'll see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to get the data in php as,

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$data->name  // to access name
```

---

OR

add the jquery and
change the headers,

```
$http({
    url: "process.php",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: $.param($scope.formData)
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

in **php**

```
$name= $_POST['name'];
```

---

if you need to change the headers of all ajax requests then do it in config block for EX,

```
app.config(['$httpProvider' , '$routeProvider', function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
}])
```

Comment: And also, it is possible to change a content-type in the AngularJS.

Comment: If I add the `header` section nothing change, same problem. If I add the `$.param` I get ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: If I use `file_get_content` I get `POST http://localhost:8888/Angularjs/process.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: its `file_get_contents` not `file_get_content` u missed last `s` i think :)

Comment: `$.param` is a jQuery function, as I know. So, if you don't have jQuery in the project, than you may try to find a replacement for it. something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22583081/2737720

Comment: ow yeas needs include the jquery also :)

Comment: I'd like also to mention a cause of such behavior as it may be useful. AngularJS by default sends POST requests with application/json Content-Type. But PHP populates the $_POST array only for requests with Content-Type header set to either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data (probably, this behavior can be changed by some extensions). So, the data is successfully sent from the client, but not parsed automatically by the server.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was a missing `jquery` and the `headers` section!

Answer (score 1):

> **TL;DR** Aha! since `$scope.formData` is an Object? Then do `JSON.stringify()`.
>
> **TL;DR** Aha! since `$errors` is an array? Then do `json_encode()`.

**JS:**

```
$http.post('process.php', JSON.stringify( $scope.formData ) ) ...
```

**PHP:**

```
json_encode($errors);
```

**Note:**

```
write: JSON.stringify. json_encode()
read: JSON.parse(), json_decode()
```

As for [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), it defaults in header settings ( *Note: `dataType` )

**Setting HTTP Headers**

> The $http service will automatically add certain HTTP headers to all
>   requests. These defaults can be fully configured by accessing the
>   $httpProvider.defaults.headers configuration object, which currently
>   contains this default configuration:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common (headers that are common for all requests):
Accept: application/json, text/plain, * / *
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post: (header defaults for POST requests)
Content-Type: application/json
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.put (header defaults for PUT requests)
Content-Type: application/json
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that in process.php the $_POST is always empty

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi, i updated the answer on JSON,stringify( object ), since $scope.form is an object. See how that goes. Hope that helps.