# RouteParams in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I am trying to pass a routeParam to a $http.post in my Angular controller, but I dont seem to be passing the value correctly.  Here is what I have below.  Am an not using the $routeParams correctly?  When using `$scope.event_id = $routeParams.eventId;` the partial page renders correctly with `Event: {{event_id}}` or Event: 5 for example.

I need the $http.post to be `php/getItem.php?itemID=5`

**The HTML passing the event_id:**

```
<a href="#/{{event.event_id}}">{{event.event_name}}</a>
```

**The routeProvider:**

```
var pvApp = angular.module('pvApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
pvApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        .when('/:eventId', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/event_detail.html',
            controller  : 'eventController'
        });

});
```

**The Controller:**

```
pvApp.controller('eventController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    // $scope.event_id = $routeParams.eventId;

      $http.post("php/getItem.php?itemID="+$routeParams.eventId).success(function(data){
            $scope.items = data;
           });

});
```

**The Partial Page:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Event: {{event_id}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? Check your browser's *Network* console to see if the POST request looks right and what the response is. Are you sure you want to use POST? You don't seem to be passing any data

Comment: Network console is showing `getItem.php?itemID=5` listed so I am thinking my issue lies in the output such as `<h2>Event: {{event_id}}</h2>`  Perhaps this is what is not formatted correctly?

Comment: ... and what does the **response** look like? And why are you using POST?

Comment: Response is exactly what I need it to be - JSON from MySQL.  Changed to GET and same response.  Using `$item_id = $_GET['itemID'];`when passing this to getItem.php

Comment: So what's the problem? You don't appear to be using `$scope.items` anywhere. If you put `console.log(data)` in your `success` callback, does the logged value look correct / is it logged at all?

Comment: Sorted this out.  I was not using a ng-repeat to sort through `item in items` then using `{{item.event_id}}`.  Thanks for helping me with the network console check.

Answer (score 0):

**first check**

```
console.log($routeParams.eventId);
```

is print the event_id on the console correctly.

**Then**

Note that your using a `POST` request but your `url` like `GET` request.

change the request like below and try,

```
 $http({
    url: 'php/getItem.php',
    method: "POST",
    data: { itemID : $routeParams.eventId },        
}).succes...
```

OR

```
 $http.post('php/getItem.php', { itemID:$routeParams.eventId }).success...
```

*here you can get the data in Php as,*

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$data->itemID // to access name
```

---

OR

```
 $http({
    url: 'php/getItem.php',
    method: "POST",
    data: { itemID : $routeParams.eventId },   
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},     
}).succes...
```

*In Php,*

```
$name= $_POST['itemID'];
```

may be this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242101/send-data-to-a-php-script-with-angularjs/30242332#30242332) will helps you.

Comment: That's going to put `itemID=5` in the POST request body. OP seems to indicate it should be in the URL